# Export Svg from Angular Library

Tags: angular, svg, shared-libraries, angular-library

I am creating a design library, and would like to include some basic SVG to it, so that if user do not add/override they will still be displayed as backup.

I created a folder in my library

```
assets/
 => svg/
   => alert.svg
   => success.svg
   => trash.svg
   => ...
```

I then added this folder to `ng-package.json`

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/libs/ui",
  "assets": ["src/assets"],
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/index.ts"
  }
}
```

then I would like to load those svg in my library, so in my module folder I do :

```
constructor(private iconReg: SvgIconRegistryService) {
    Object.entries({
        alert: 'assets/svg/alert.svg',
        info: 'assets/svg/info.svg',
        success: 'assets/svg/success.svg',
        warning: 'assets/svg/warning.svg',
    }).forEach(([key, value]) => {
        this.iconReg.loadSvg(value, key)?.subscribe();
    });
}
```

Sadly, the src are not found when the library is used :

> message: "Http failure response for http://localhost:4200/assets/svg/success.svg: 404 Not Found"
> name: "HttpErrorResponse"

Comment: Take a look to the [docs](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries#managing-assets-in-a-library) Here say that you sould include in exports in package.json (Sorry, I can help you more, because I had no experience about this)

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your `ng-package.josn` export assets like below:

```
{
  "$schema": "../../node_modules/ng-packagr/ng-package.schema.json",
  "dest": "../../dist/libs/ui",
  "assets": ["./assets"],
  "lib": {
    "entryFile": "src/index.ts"
  }
}
```

- `tsconfig.lib.json` path do not work in angular libraries, so after your change you may have to edit manually the import of the assets with relative path.

Now run `ng build custom-project --prod`. It then appear in your dist folder.

Then, Add those files into your `angular.json` file:

```
{
  "assets": [
    {
      "glob": "**/*",
      "input": "./node_modules/your-project/assets",
      "output": "/assets/"
    }
  ],
  "styles" : [
    "node_modules/your-project/assets/css-file.css"
  ],
  "scripts" : [
    "node_modules/your-project/assets/js-file.js"
  ]
}
```

Comment: THanks for the reply. How would this work if it is a publishable library ? would I require user to edit their application angular.json ?

Comment: No, the addresses will be relative and inside package they are accessible from it's components. @Bobby

Comment: Then it is not ideal, since the point of a shared library would be to also share some SVG. Like FontAwesome does*

Comment: Font awesome does it with css class not addressing svg directly.

Answer (score 0):

One alternative I can suggest is instead of exporting files,
you could just create one component.
In html part you could place svg file content and access them using input parameter.
May be by passing svg name you could access them.
Even other style parameters to svg can be kept as input to the component.

Answer (score 0):

i suggest you to create a html and component and css file.then copy your svg in html file with **svg tag** then put the svg css in css file and import the css in your component.